# Do I need a laptop with 100% srgb color coverage for UX/UI design?

Tags: gui-design, color

I know for the UX part it doesn't matter but what if I'm using tools like figma and creating wireframes UI elements do I need a top quality screen or will I be just fine with a cheap gaming laptop that has a display quality of 60% srgb / 45% NTSC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what's important to remember with any UX/UI design is that every person is different.

In that, they will be viewing what you produce on a range of devices, with various profiles, with a range of different visual capacity in various physical environments.

It's definitely worth getting away from trying to make every colour/design pixel perfect and work more toward effective systematic design and accessible outputs, trust the science rather than your eyes (most of the time).

The one thing I would say however is that it *can* be useful to view designs on a range of devices, but it's likely more important to consider form factors, physical environments of usage and low network speed rather than purely colour profiles.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don’t even *need* any laptop at all for being a UX designer and none as a UI designer either.